# Moving Static content from Application server to web Server for better performance

Tags: performance, webserver

i am running application on WebSphere 6, as any other application my application has both static content and Dynamic content, now i am planing to move all My Static contents like JS,CSS and Images to Tomcat 6 
 i have started with images, i put all images in webApp folder
now my url to access this image is `http://localh0st:8080/MYAPP/visa.gif`

in MY Jsp i am accessing this Image like below

```
<img class=card title=VISA alt=VISA src="http://localh0st:8080/Hello/MC.gif"></img>
```

mentioning all the URL seems not best way in the JSP,
can you please suggest me some best practices on this

Comment: If you are using Unix based OS. Try R-Sync

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would install an http server in front your application (Apache for instance)

The Apache server (http, not tomcat) is very efficient to deliver content and can also proxy request to another server.

Then I would suggest you to move all you static resources in the Apache http server, and add the proxy module to Apache http and forward all the request that are not gif, jpg, css, js, and whatever is not static to your websphere server.

If you manage to isolate properly everything, you will avoid rewriting all the urls of the application.